# Crash During ChoosePixelFormat in VB6

Tags: windows, opengl, graphics, vb6

I've been tasked to maintain a VB6 app; I've got some OpenGL experience but all using SDL and this one seems to manually handle all it's contexts.

The program appears to crash on a call to ChoosePixelFormat.  I'm passing in a non-null handle.  It works on most systems, so I'm guessing its a graphics driver issue, but it appears to be up to date.

Does anyone know why this function would crash instead of, say, returning an error code?  I understand the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR may have values that don't exist on a given system:

```
  .nSize = Len(glPFD)
  .nVersion = 1
  .dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP Or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL Or PFD_SUPPORT_GDI
  .iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA
  .cColorBits = 32
  .cDepthBits = 16
  .iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE
```

But would that make it crash?

Edit: On the system on which this fails, it works with a previous version in which this code was identical.  I read a forum somewhere that said loading/unloading opengl32.dll can cause gdi32.dll to break things.  This might be the case.

Edit: I've attached the full code below (it's kind of ugly, but it helped me narrow down where the crash was).  No functions return 0 before ChoosePixelFormat crashes.

```
hDCdib = CreateCompatibleDC(0) 'DC compatible with screen

Call MsgBox("Create Compatible DC " + CStr(hDCdib))


'Setup a Device Independent Bitmap Section
With bmInfo.bmiHeader
  .biSize = Len(bmInfo)
  If lngWidth = 0 Then
     .biHeight = objDest.ScaleY(objDest.Height, vbTwips, vbPixels)
     .biWidth = objDest.ScaleX(objDest.Width, vbTwips, vbPixels)
  Else
     .biHeight = objDest.ScaleY(lngHeight, vbTwips, vbPixels)
     .biWidth = objDest.ScaleX(lngWidth, vbTwips, vbPixels)
  End If

  .biPlanes = 1
  .biBitCount = 32
  .biCompression = BI_RGB 'No Compression
  .biSizeImage = 0
  .biClrImportant = 0
  .biClrUsed = 0
  .biXPelsPerMeter = 0
  .biYPelsPerMeter = 0
End With
Call MsgBox("after header")
hDIBSection = CreateDIBSection(hDCdib, bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, hBitMapData, _
              &O0, &O0)
Call MsgBox("CreateDIBSection" + CStr(hDIBSection))
'Select the DIB into a device context
hBitMapOld = SelectObject(hDCdib, hDIBSection)
Call MsgBox("SelectObject " + CStr(hBitMapOld))
'Create an OpenGL drawing area in that DIB
With glPFD
  .nSize = Len(glPFD)
  .nVersion = 1
  .dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP Or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL Or PFD_SUPPORT_GDI
  .iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA
  .cColorBits = 32
  .cDepthBits = 16
  .iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE
End With
Call MsgBox("glPFD ")
'Ignacio issue is in the next line about ChoosePixelFormat
lngFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDCdib, glPFD)
   Call MsgBox("ChoosePixelFormat " + CStr(lngFormat))
Htemp = SetPixelFormat(hDCdib, lngFormat, glPFD)
Call MsgBox("SetPixelFormat " + CStr(Htemp))
hGLrc = wglCreateContext(hDCdib)
Call MsgBox("wglCreateContext " + CStr(hGLrc))
wglMakeCurrent hDCdib, hGLrc
Call MsgBox("wglMakeCurrent ")
```

Comment: Where's the call to ChoosePixelFormat?

Comment: I've attached it to the original question, now.

Answer (score 0):

An OpenGL context on a DIB isn't accelerated, so you'll get a software renderer (at least that was the case some years back and I doubt it's changed, although I could be wrong).  If you want to do hardware accelerated rendering, create a window and use that to generate your GL context.  If you want, hide the window.

Comment: I'm actual in charge of modernizing the system (it'll be a Java rewrite with actual hardware acceleration), but I'm also in charge of maintaining the old version until it's done.

So, I don't need to worry about making this version fast; it just can't crash, like it is now.

The more I read, the more the crash sounds like a graphics driver issue (I've heard about gdi32.dll and opengl32.dll not getting along well together and causing stuff like this).

Comment: Sure.  I don't envy you having to maintain that.  We still have a VB6 app we're supporting at work and luckily I'm not the guy for that :-).  Still, a solution to your problem might be as I said, to create an invisible window to get a context, do the render to that and then grab the bits from the back buffer.  I shouldn't think it would be a huge amount of code.

Comment: @Robinson: In a hidden window for rendering to yield something usefull, one must use either a Framebuffer Object, or use that window as proxy to a PBuffer.

Comment: Yes.  Given the age of the app, that might be a problem in itself.